# Atomic integer vs syncronization

Tags: java, multithreading

Please advise is java.util.concurrent.atomic package is another alternative to achieve synchronization let say there is a variable and 10 different threads are incrementing it then what is the role of atomic integer in that case in context of synchronization..!

Comment: `AtomicInteger` guarantees atomicity and visibility to all threads. It is lower latency than using `synchronized` over all access to the variable to serve as a memory barrier; both support more complex atomic operations than mere assignment and access, e.g. incrementing (unlike `volatile int`).

Comment: @oldrinb where does the visibility come from?

Comment: @MattBall [see specification for `java.util.concurrent.atomic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)... "`get` has the memory effects of reading a `volatile` variable ... `set` has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a `volatile` variable."

Comment: @MattBall see [§17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)... "A write to a `volatile` field (§8.3.1.4) *happens-before* every subsequent read of that field."

Comment: Correcting my first comment: it *has* (rather than 'is') lower latency; to *enforce* (rather than 'serve as') a memory barrier."

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a single integer to increment, then yes - `AtomicInteger` allows you to achieve that easily, efficiently and robustly without synchronization.

If you need to do more than that - for example, if you *actually* need to update more than one variable, and the *pair* of them have to be updated as a single unit, then you'd want to use synchronization.